# Calulate norms of orthogonals vectors

Tags: orthogonality

I need to calculate 
$(||2u+3v||^2 - ||2u-3v||^2)$
knowing that u and v are orthogonal.
I don't understand how i can calculate without any information on those vectors and why the fact that these vectors are orthogonal help to that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint**

For any vectors $x,y$, you have

$$\Vert x \Vert^2 - \Vert y\Vert^2 =\langle x-y , x+y \rangle$$

Comment: so x and y are vectors ? and the result is the scalar product of x-y and x+y ?

Comment: Just plug in $x=2u+3v$

Comment: And $y=2u-3v$ to get the conclusion

Comment: @WitzigAdrien Yes. This is an identity satisfied by the inner product.

Comment: but how can i do the dot product of vectors i don't know anything ?

Comment: Have you tried to do the plug in that we suggested?

Comment: yes but i came to <6v.4u> how can i get further ?

Comment: The inner product is bilinear...

Comment: Also use the fact that the $u$ and $v$ vectors are perpendicular. That would simplify the scalar product

Comment: i think i understand, so (||2u+3v||^2 − ||2u−3v||^2)  = 0 ?

Comment: That is right!!